# phantomjs via watir-webdriver, not handling javascript alerts

Tags: ruby, phantomjs, watir-webdriver

I’m trying to automate some tasks on a webpage, and part of it includes clicking a link that’ll show a javascript alert where you have to press “OK”. Trouble is, when it gets to that point, it fails with the following error

```
/Users/username/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:66:in `create_response': unexpected response, code=405, content-type="text/plain" (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
Invalid Command Method - Request => {"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3","Cache-Control":"no-cache","Connection":"close","Host":"127.0.0.1:8910","User-Agent":"Ruby"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"GET","url":"/alert_text","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"alert_text","directory":"/","path":"/alert_text","relative":"/alert_text","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/alert_text","queryKey":{},"chunks":["alert_text"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/6772bf50-2ad9-11e3-86e7-55e618e30fa2/alert_text"}
    from /Users/username/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:66:in `request'
    from /Users/username/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
    from /Users/username/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:634:in `raw_execute'
    from /Users/username/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:612:in `execute'
    from /Users/username/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:150:in `getAlertText'
    from /Users/username/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/alert.rb:9:in `initialize'
    from /Users/username/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/target_locator.rb:76:in `new'
    from /Users/username/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/target_locator.rb:76:in `alert'
    from /Users/username/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.4/lib/watir-webdriver/alert.rb:93:in `assert_exists'
    from /Users/username/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.4/lib/watir-webdriver/alert.rb:37:in `ok'
    from ./olx:21:in `block in <main>'
    from ./olx:19:in `times'
    from ./olx:19:in `<main>'
```

Searching online, it seems like the trouble may be [related to ghostdriver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/20) and that maybe phantomjs can’t do it, but that notion seems a bit weird to me (it’s called phantom***js***, after all, and an alert is pretty basic javascript), but maybe I’m looking at it wrong.

Running the script with chrome, it works flawlessly.

Comment: Check this and let me know http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151222/unable-to-connect-to-browser-using-ruby-selenium-webdriver

Comment: I still get the same error.

Comment: Would you mind capture a screenshot to see if the alert box is there?

Comment: Nope, the alert box is not visible on the screenshot.

Comment: Could the solution provided here help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215713/watir-webdriver-clicking-javascript-button?

Comment: No, that also does nothing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a known issue where PhantomJS doesn't handle JavaScript properly.
One workaround is to disable the alert box by running:

`@browser.execute_script("window.confirm = function(){return true;}");`

Basically, the steps you want to follow are:

1. Go to the page
2. Run the command above
3. Click 'Delete' (or whatever that triggers the alertbox)
4. And it will automatically click 'Ok' for you.

Comment: How can something have *js* in the name and handle javascript poorly? Thank you very much, I had a bounty on this that already expired, I didn’t think I’d get an answer. Is there anyway I can further repay you for the answer?

Comment: I didn't understand your question clearly. Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: I was just venting on the first question — *phantomjs* has *js* in the name (for javascript), so it’s a bit ironic that it doesn’t handle javascript properly. The idea is that it is scriptable *with* javascript, yes, but still. Regarding the second question, is there anyway I can thank you further, besides accepting the answer? I had a bounty on this that unfortunately had already expired, so it feels a bit wrong that those points went to waste.

Comment: Ha! I dont know. I just started using stackoverflow. ;) but I'm here to help other people as well.

Answer (score -1):

Sure,

Before go to action run it:

browser.execute_script("window.confirm = function(){return true;}");

It's help confirm popup.